# Could not find module `Test.QuickCheck' on Ubuntu

Tags: testing, haskell, ubuntu

I'm importing QuickCheck at the top of my file:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
...
```

Compiling the file with `ghc Lab1.hs` gives me this error:

```
Lab1.hs:1:8:
    Could not find module `Test.QuickCheck'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I tried an apt-cache search for `quickcheck` and got a dire list of packages. Tried installing `libghc-test-framework-dev` just because I thought the name seemed appropriate, but the error persists.

How do I install the QuickCheck module?

Comment: Knowing Debian's naming scheme, I would guess `libghc-QuickCheck-dev`, but I don't have such a machine handy to check.

Comment: Knowing Debian's human-driven RPC scheme (website), I have found [`libghc-quickcheck2-dev`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libghc-quickcheck2-dev), but I don't have such a machine handy to install in.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're interested in managing your Haskell packages outside of your package manager (which may be beneficial if you're interested in using the latest versions of things) then Cabal is the Haskell package manager which would allow you to do

```
apt-get install cabal-install
cabal update
cabal install QuickCheck
```

to make QuickCheck available globally.

What's more recommended of late however is to use the `sandbox` feature of Cabal. This is very similar to Python's `virtualenv` or Ruby's `bundle` if you're more familiar with those. To do this, you must create a "cabalized" project

```
cabal init        # in an empty directory
```

and then put `QuickCheck` (and your other library dependencies) in the `build-depends:` slot of the generated `<folder name>.cabal` file.

After you've done this you use Cabal for all further package management and compilation commands.

```
cabal sandbox init                  # creates your local package sandbox
cabal install --only-dependencies   # gets and installs all the build-dependencies

cabal repl                          # starts up GHCi in the local sandbox
cabal build                         # configures and builds the local project

cabal sandbox delete                # cleans up the sandbox
```

Comment: I did: `sudo apt-get install cabal-install` and `cabal update` and could then proceed with `cabal install QuickCheck` as above. The sandbox thing wasn't appropriate in my case but it might come in handy further on. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked well! I'll add those steps to the answer for future visitors if you don't mind.

Comment: cabal sandbox feature is no longer available. If possible can you maybe add an update ? @J.Abrahamson

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04.1:

```
sudo apt-get install libghc-quickcheck2-dev
```

Before:

```
> :m +Test.QuickCheck

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Test.QuickCheck'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

After:

```
Prelude> :m +Test.QuickCheck
Prelude Test.QuickCheck>
```

Comment: Tried it again just now on a ubuntu:14.04 docker image with `docker run -i -t --rm ubuntu:14.04`, and it still appears to work.  Not sure how to format code in a comment, but the steps were: `apt-get update; apt-get install libghc-quickcheck2-dev; ghci` followed by `:m +Test.QuickCheck`

Comment: I managed to install and use quickcheck using cabal. Initially, using only apt-get it was impossible.  Anyway, it works now for me.